# Deleting taxonomy terms and relationships on a custom post_type when a user is deleted

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy

First off, I have a custom plugin that registers a custom post_type. When a user signs up on the site, a post is created using the custom post_type. The post is populated by the user's company name [post_title] and when others sign up under the same company name, they are saved as tags to that post.

When a user is deleted via the admin dashboard, the remaining taxonomy terms and relationships are still there and causes these users to be shown on a custom account page [front-end], even though they have been deleted. I think the issue is with `wp_set_object_terms` not setting the relationships back.

I ran multiple tests and dumped the vars and everything looked good to go but on final testing, all associates were missing and the terms were still in the database.

```
public function removeUserFromCompany( $user_id ) {
    // hook into user_delete to remove associate tag from custom_post_type
    // and all terms and relationships in DB
    // this is for deleting a user's account from the admin menu
    // add_action( 'user_delete', 'removeUserFromCompany' );

    global $wpdb;

    // get all metadata for $current_user from wp_usermeta table
    $user = get_user_meta($user_id, '', false);

    // $term = term_id used in wp_term_taxonomy
    $term = maybe_unserialize($user['company_associate'][0]);

    $myposts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
        'post_status'=>'private',
        'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                'taxonomy' => 'company_associate',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $term['term_id']
                )
            )
        )
    );

    $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms($myposts[0]->ID, 'company_associate');

    $get_term = get_term_by('id', $term['term_id'], 'company_associate');

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($object_terms as $terms) {

        // match company associate terms from post_type with deleted user's terms from user_meta
        // unset deleted user's object terms  
        if ( $terms->term_id == $get_term->term_id && $terms->name == $get_term->name ) {

            unset($object_terms[$i]);
        } 

        $i++;

    }

    // return object with deleted user's unset taxonomy
    wp_set_object_terms($myposts[0]->ID, $object_terms, 'company_associate');

    // delete remaining taxonomy terms from the user
    wp_delete_term($get_term->term_id, 'company_associate');

}
```

Would it be easier to delete these records using queries instead?